# Create Oracle sequence via execute immediate without pipe || operator

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

`create sequence s1 ;`

```
declare
    v_value    number;
    v_sql_stmt varchar2(4000);
    v_seq_name varchar2(30);
BEGIN
   v_seq_name:='S1'; -- **this is dynamic and the sequence will be passed in the proc as input parameter at runtime**
   v_sql_stmt:= 'select :v_seq_name'||'.nextval from dual' ; 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_stmt INTO v_value USING v_seq_name ;

--**below is working but I dont want to do in this way because of sql injection issue, let me know how to fix the above**
--EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || v_seq_name || '.nextval from dual' INTO v_value;

dbms_output.put_line(v_value);
end;
/
```

the above code is throwing error, please help to fix.

If you run the commented code then it will run but I dont want to use || in execute immediate. I want to use colon : only.

the sequence name will be passed at run time. The above code will be converted to a proc later.

Comment: BTW, sequence names (and column/table etc names) can be longer from Oracle version 12. So better start using `VARCHAR2(128 BYTES)` if your code will be used later on in a new database.

Comment: what is your sql injection concern ??

Comment: Using `||` in execute immediate is the only way to make this work. `:parameters` are for SQL variables not database object names. Sorry but that's the way the language is defined.

Comment: Anyway, what is the value of the proposed function? At some point you have to reference the sequence name, so why not do it **in code**? Then it can be validated by the compiler and located by dependency analyses (which is not true of a string value passed to a "generic function").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your concern about SQL injection. To my knowledge, table/column/sequence names cannot be specified with bind variables. However, you could do a simple check before executing the unsafe code:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE s1;
CREATE SEQUENCE s2;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p(seq_name VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER AS
    v_value    number;
    v_sql_stmt varchar2(4000);
    v_seq_name varchar2(128 BYTE);
BEGIN
  v_seq_name:= DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(seq_name);
  v_sql_stmt:= 'select '||v_seq_name||'.nextval from dual'; 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_stmt INTO v_value;
  RETURN v_value;
END p;
/
```

If a valid name is used, everything works as expected:

```
select p('s1') from dual;
1

select p('s2') from dual;
2
```

However, if `seq_name` is not a valid Oracle name, `DBMS_ASSERT` throws an exception:

```
select p('1; DROP TABLE x') from dual;

ORA-44003: invalid SQL name
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 215
ORA-06512: at "WFL.P", line 6
44003. 0000 -  "invalid SQL name"
```

Comment: in addition to checking just the format, a check via, say, USER_SEQUENCES can be done to confirm the sequence does exist indeed. This itself can be a query with bind variables

Comment: Using DBMS_ASSERT is the proper way to protect against SQL injection. The suggestion of validating the sequence is sensible, but also highlights the pointless over-engineering of a function to do this.